# Python usage of regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

How can I extract *string1#string2* from the bellow line?

```
<![CDATA[<html><body><p style="margin:0;">string1#string2</p></body></html>]]>
```

The # character and the structure of the line is always the same.

Comment: Quick, dirty, and without regex: `newline = oldline.replace('<![CDATA[<html><body><p style="margin:0;">','').replace('</p></body></html>]]>','')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use a regex:

```
>>> re.search(r"<p.*?>(.+?)</p>", txt).group(1)
'string1#string2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to refer you to this [gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags):

In synthesis a regex is not the appropriate tool for this job
Also have you tried an [XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) parser instead?

EDIT:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
a = "<html><body><p style=\"margin:0;\">string1#string2</p></body></html>"
root = ET.fromstring(a)
c = root[0][0].text

OUT:
c
'string1#string2'

d = c.replace('#', ' ').split()
Out: 
d 
['string1', 'string2']
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The linked answer is epic, but that doesn't make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, buggy, not reliable:

```
line.replace('<![CDATA[<html><body><p style="margin:0;">', "").replace('</p></body></html>]]>', "").split("#")
```

Comment: or just `line[42:57]`

Answer (score 1):

```
re.search(r'[^>]+#[^<]+',s).group()
```